# Greedy Algorithm for planar graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, coloring, planar-graphs

Consider the following coloring algorithm for planar graphs:

1. Create a stack $S$ with the vertices of $G$ as follows:

(a) If $v$ is has the lowest degree vertex in $G$, add $v$ to $S$ and change
to $G$ for $G-{v}$.

2. The first vertex of $S$, color it with color 1
3. The next vertex of $S$ color it from the minimum integer that has not been
   used on any of its neighbors.
4. Repeat 3. until all vertices are colored.

How would you improve the algorithm in such a way that the resulting coloration
always use at most 5 colors?

I've been trying to improve this algorithm as it is required, but since this algoritm is kind of Greddy Algorithm "brother" we can use at most 6 colors, since every vertex in a planar graph has at most $d(v) ≤ 5$, How can I improve this?  I think the part we can improve this is between step 3 and 4

Comment: "every vertex in a planar graph has at most $d(v)=5$" This is certainly false. There is no upper bound on the degree of a vertex in a planar graph.

Comment: So, what do you think, Lmath?

Comment: Are you still here, Lmath?

Comment: It's impolite, Lmath, to post a question & then run away.